# How to serialize http::HeaderMap into JSON?

Tags: http, rust, aws-sdk-rust

What is the proper way of serializing HTTP request headers ([`http::HeaderMap`](https://docs.rs/http/0.1.15/http/struct.HeaderMap.html)) into JSON in Rust?

I am implementing an AWS Lambda function and I would like to have a simple echo function for debugging.

```
use lambda_http::{lambda, IntoResponse, Request};
use lambda_runtime::{error::HandlerError, Context};
use log::{self, info};
use simple_logger;
use std::error::Error;

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    simple_logger::init_with_level(log::Level::Debug)?;
    info!("Starting up...");
    lambda!(handler);

    return Ok(());
}

fn handler(req: Request, ctx: Context) -> Result<impl IntoResponse, HandlerError> {
    Ok(format!("{}", req.headers()).into_response())
}
```

Is there an easy way to convert `req.headers()` to JSON and return?

Comment: So you do not care *whatsoever* what the format of the returned JSON is? Just so long as it's something that counts as JSON?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no "proper" way to do so. Just like there's no "proper" way to automatically implement `Display` for a struct, there's no One True Way to serialize some piece of data to JSON.

If all you need is to get *something* that counts as JSON, and since this is for debugging, I'd just print out the debug form of the headers and then convert it into a [`Value`](https://docs.rs/serde_json/1.0.39/serde_json/enum.Value.html):

```
use http::{header::HeaderValue, HeaderMap}; // 0.1.17
use serde_json; // 1.0.39 

fn convert(headers: &HeaderMap<HeaderValue>) -> serde_json::Value {
    format!("{:?}", headers).into()
}
```

If you want something a bit more structured, you can (lossily!) convert the headers to a `HashMap<String, Vec<String>>`. This type can be trivially serialized to a JSON object:

```
use http::{header::HeaderValue, HeaderMap}; // 0.1.17
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn convert(headers: &HeaderMap<HeaderValue>) -> HashMap<String, Vec<String>> {
    let mut header_hashmap = HashMap::new();
    for (k, v) in headers {
        let k = k.as_str().to_owned();
        let v = String::from_utf8_lossy(v.as_bytes()).into_owned();
        header_hashmap.entry(k).or_insert_with(Vec::new).push(v)
    }
    header_hashmap
}
```